# Parsing Android JSON

Tags: php, android, json, parsing

I've been trying to parse the following in my android application but cant figure out how to get that far down the branch. I want to be able to get "description" in "myc" This is what i have:

```
{
"status": 0,
"result": [
    {
        "id": 20,
        "object_metadata": {
            "name": "David",
            "myc": [
                {
                    "description": "Hello world"
                },
                {
                    "description": "Goodbye World"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]

}
```

Comment: Can you post your java code as well ?

Answer (score 1):

```
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonstring);
    JSONArray array =  obj.getJSONArray("result").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("object_metadata").getJSONArray("myc");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        String description = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("description");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [Google GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). You can make a java class (or a model), implement getters and setters, and easily get and set every value. Parsing JSON via `JSONObject` can be frustrating when you are going to manipulate in deeper structure of the JSON specified.

Answer (score 0):

try below code:-

```
try
{

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject("ur json");
    String status = json.getString("status");
    JSONArray result = json.getJSONArray("result");
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++)
    {
        JSONObject json_result = result.getJSONObject(i);
        String id = json_result.getString("id");
        JSONObject object_metadata = json_result.getJSONObject("object_metadata");
        String name = object_metadata.getString("name");
        JSONArray myc = object_metadata.getJSONArray("myc");
        for (int j = 0; j < myc.length(); j++)
        {
            JSONObject myc_value = myc.getJSONObject(i);
            String description = myc_value.getString("description");
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // TODO: handle exception
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```